MacOs equivalent of adding a user to the linux dialout group on for permissions setup for UART communication
I'm working on a project where I'm interfacing with some hardware and want to monitor the data from some sensors using a specific tool. The tool doesn't have official support for MacOS but I've confirmed from contributors it's possible to run on MacOS.
Part of the setup (for Linux) requires the applicable user to be added to the dialout group for UART communication:
$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout [user]
From what I've found already it seems like equivalent of usermod for zsh is dscl, and adding user to a group would be something like this:
$ sudo dscl . append /Groups/[groupname] GroupMembership [user] 
I checked which groups the applicable user is already part of with groups [user] on the off chance it was already added, and dialout wasn't one of them. Then it occurred to me that maybe the equivalent group for MacOS is named something other than dialout, so I listed all the groups with dscl . list /groups and sure enough, I don't see dialout, only dialer.
Is that the right group? Will $ sudo dscl . append /Groups/dialer GroupMembership [user]  do what I think it will..? Thanks in advance.

I don't think there's a direct equivalent. If the point on Linux of adding them to the dialout group was to give them access to a device special file representing a serial port (say for example /dev/ttys0), then on macOS you should determine which device file represents the serial port in question and then figure out how to alter permissions to give the right users access. Perhaps you could chgrp(8) the device file to make its group dialer instead of its default which is probably wheel. Or maybe you could add an ACL to the device file to give the dialer group access.

Okay thanks, that approach makes more sense. Is the param 8 for chgrp an actual option or just an artibutrary number for an example. It looks like there's a param for a filename, so in your example that that would be /dev/ttys0, right? Also, ACLs are Access Control Lists? I'm somewhat new to this arena, thanks in advance.

Oops, when I wrote that I must have been working too quickly. Sometimes when talking about commands, system calls, special files, and other fundamental Unix concepts that are documented in "the Unix manual", and especially when we talk about the "man[ual] page" for such things, we use parens at the end to mention which section of the manual it's in. 1=user commands, 8=superuser commands. But the chgrp command is a user command, so I erred when I said it was in section 8, but now it's too late to edit the comment.

And yes, ACLs are access control lists. So what I'm saying is, "look at how the Unix filesystem permissions are set on the device file that represents the serial port in question, and make sure that the users you want to use the serial port have the file access permissions they need to use (i.e. read and write) the device file.
